# How to loop through a arrays in an object and print values of only specific keys?

Tags: javascript

I have an object named `responses` that consists of arrays as keys like this

```js
responses = { 
  'Day': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10],
  'Score': [9,10,9,8,8,9,10,9,8,7],
  'Grade': ['A','O','A','B','B','A','O','A','B','C']
}
```

I want to loop through the object and only print the `Score` and `Grade` values, like this:

```
9   'A'
10  'O'
9   'A'
.    .
.    .
.    .
7   'C'
```

How do print this?

Comment: Research [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) or [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loops.

Comment: Print how? Console log? Add each to separate elements in a grid?

Comment: Also note that the data structure you have is an object literal with properties which contain arrays. It is quite different to JSON which is a method of serialising data. I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+loop+array+specific+index+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+loop+array+print+spcific+keys+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use for in loop. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) for further information.

```
for (const response in responses) 
{ 
    if (response === "Score")
    {
        responses[response].forEach(item => {
            console.log(item); 
        }); 
        
        // do something else 
    } 
    else if (response === "Grade") 
    {
        responses[response].forEach(item => {
            console.log(item); 
        }); 

        // do something else 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by index callback of `Array.prototype.map()` function.

Try:

```js
const responses = {
  Day: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  Score: [9, 10, 9, 8, 8, 9, 10, 9, 8, 7],
  Grade: ['A', 'O', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'O', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
};

responses.Day.map(
  (day, i) => console.log(responses.Score[i], responses.Grade[i]) // 9 B
);
```

Comment: a forEach is better suited here since nothing is returned in the map